# How to calculate Valance, Arousal, and Dominance (VAD) for each document?

Tags: python, r, sentiment-analysis

I have a list of around 50 documents. I am trying to calculated the VAD scores using the NRC-VAD dictionary for each of the documents. Most methods / documentation online relates to calculated VAD scores for each of the word within a document. However, I am trying to figure out how to then compile these scores into an overall VAD score for the document as a whole.

I believe one would be able to calculate the VAD scores for the entire document by taking the weighted average of the VAD scores for each word. Here are the detailed steps below:

1. Parse the document into a list of unique words and calculate the frequency of each word.
2. Merge this unique list of words with the NRC-VAD dictionary - omitting words that are not captured in the dictionary.
3. Calculate the relative frequency of each word after inner_joining with the NRC-VAD dictionary.
4. Obtain the VAD scores for the document by calculating the weighted average (using the relative frequency as weights and the respective VAD provided by the dictionary).

Would this be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a reasonable approach.

My concern would be that the interesting signal might get drowned out by the averaging. But maybe if that happens then it is just a sign that the document has no strong sentiment?

If the documents are all similar length and structure, then I think the resulting averages should at least carry some meaning for ranking them.

I'd also calculate the weighted s.d. along with the weighted mean. E.g. If the valence mean is near 0.5 and the s.d. is low it could indicate a document that doesn't use emotive words, whereas the same mean but a higher s.d. could indicate there is a lot of both love and hate going on.

If you were looking for an academic description of best practice, the Bing Liu book, and [this chapter](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/sentiment-analysis/document-sentiment-classification/FE9AC1687D88C10B7548964AD08A6880) looks to be the best reference.